# Port 2103 Zephyr-clt

Tags: ports

After a long time of worrying about my network being secure and finally understanding the basic job of the ports I would see open.  I recently noticed port 2103 Zephyr-clt and port 2105 eklogin open on my daughters computer.  I asked her if she was "Instant Messaging" as that seemed like what the ports were for, but she said no.  It was near midnight but I did not think she would fib about it? She did just add a printer that day. Can anyone tell me why these would suddenly appear open?

Comment: This sounds like a general purpose computer problem which is off topic here and should be asked on superuser.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

port like zephyr-clt and msmq are used by some antivirus application like Kaspersky and other, to monitor the devices like printer and router which might be  connected to machine , so, that an antivirus program can also prevent network attacks. you can stop them , by disabling your antivirus network defender option.